# Change code from Swift 2 to swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, swift4

I'm new in Swift and i want your help please.

I am writing a code from an tutorial swift 2 and i want to write in swift 4.

```
    let imgManager = PHImageManager.default()
    let requestOptions = PHImageManager()
    requestOptions.synchronous = true  //error:Value of type 'PHImageManager' has no member 'synchronous'
    requestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat   // error:Value of type 'PHImageManager' has no member 'deliveryMode'
```

Comment: Could you show the PHImageManager function?

Comment: Typo? I don’t know the API but it looks like you have to write something like `let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()`. Two different instances of `PHImageManager` right after another doesn’t make any sense.

Comment: Replace PHImageManager to PHImageRequestOptions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be like this,

```
let imgManager = PHImageManager.default()
let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
requestOptions.isSynchronous = true
requestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
```

**requestoptions** is `PHImageRequestOptions()` not `PHImageManager()`

Please read more about [PHImageManager apple class reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phimagemanager?changes=_1)